# add image in right side of container

Tags: html, css

I want to a an image right side of the container without using bootstrap

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img/logo.jpg"/> 
</div>
```

i have added code above the cotainer like this

```
<div style="float: right;margin-top: 100px;margin-bottom: -100%;margin-right: 2%;margin-left: 95%;">
    <div><img src="img/AD.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

It's working but not looks good in mobile view.

[image]

Is it possible to do it?
any help highly appriciate,
Thanks.

Comment: use media query  and change css to remove (float:right)  width less than 768 or 480 whatver you want

Comment: what you want to show at left side of container.

Comment: @NitinDhomse i want to put a vertical advertisement

Comment: you are placing your advertise at right side here ( i.e AD.jpg), what will be at left

Comment: @NitinDhomse i want to add an advertisment right side of my container

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/teutak/yq5e5c57/4/ @Udara

Comment: Instead of posting images you should setup jsfiddle or code snippet in the question so that we can get more idea on the progress. Doing that will save a lot of time for you and the people who are trying to help.

Comment: Here i got my answer:
[jsfiddle.net/dfsvj4tg](http://jsfiddle.net/dfsvj4tg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to position the boxes use `float`, for better padding-calculation set them to `border-box` and for equal-height boxes you could go with `flexbox` take a look at that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsvj4tg/

Comment: Is it any possible way to do without bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry i misread the "without Bootstrap" in your post. You can easily use a container div with `overflow:hidden;` and then set the img inside the container `float:right;`

Comment: I think you didn't get what i want. So i attached a image. Please look at that.

Comment: that's a basic positioning. you take a wrapper, let's call it "box" with `overflow:hidden;` and inside it you do a "container" div with `float:left; width:75%;` and a "advertisement" div with `float:right; width:15%;`

Comment: Sorry I chage the image. I want to keep the container in middle and put and advertisement right side of that.

Comment: Thank you very much i got my answer there